# Constraint to randomize elements of an array such that at least one is a multiple of 4

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I want to write a constraint to randomize an array with the following requirements:

1. Sum of all array elements must be 17
2. Array must have at least one element which is multiple of 4.
3. Size of an array can be anything.

I have written code using a helper array which works if I fix the size of array.  If I don't fix it, the code exits with this warning:

```
Warning-[CNST-LASW] Constraint large array size warning
testbench.sv, 225
Variable ind_arr.size() has value > 10000, which may cause severe 
performance degradation.
Please try to reduce the array size.
```

I have fixed the size of array:

```
class c;
  rand bit[7:0] arr[];
  rand bit[7:0] ind_arr[];

  constraint c1_arr {arr.sum() ==17;arr.size() == 10;}
  constraint c2_ind_arr {unique {ind_arr};           
                           ind_arr.size() inside {[1:arr.size()-1]};      
                           foreach(ind_arr[i])
                           ind_arr[i] inside {[0:arr.size()-1]};
                          }

  constraint c2_mul_4 { foreach(ind_arr[i])
                           ((arr[ind_arr[i]]) % 4)==0;
                         }
endclass

module m1;
  c obj;
  initial
   begin
     obj=new();
     repeat(5)
     begin
      obj.randomize();
      $display("array is %p",obj);
     end
    end
endmodule
```

Is there a better way of doing it?
If I fix the array size, it doesn't satisfy the third condition which says size of array can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 3<sup>rd</sup> requirement is impractical—you cannot not have an array of unlimited size. You must constrain the size of a dynamic array otherwise the solver will not change the size of the array. And if the size of the array is much larger than 17, then most of the elements would be 0. Also, to satisfy the 2<sup>nd</sup> requirement, the array must have at least 2 elements.

```
class c;
  rand bit[7:0] arr[];

  constraint c1_arr_sz { arr.sum() with (int'(item)) == 17; 
                         arr.size() inside {[2:20]}; }
  constraint c2_arr_m4 { arr.or() with (item % 4 == 0); }

endclass

module m1;
  c obj;
  initial
   begin
     obj=new();
     repeat(5)
     begin
      obj.randomize();
      $display("array is %p",obj);
     end
    end
endmodule
```

You need to cast each element of the array to prevent overflow when using the sum() method. And your requirements have missed the width of each element.

Comment: Hi Dave, do I need to write arr.or() with (item % 4 == 0 && item != 0) ==1 ? Also since it says at least 1 element should be multiple of 4, why cant it have just one element ?

Comment: 0 is actually a multiple of any number, so I removed `&& item !-0`. 

Can you think of a solution that would work with only one array element whose value is 17 _AND_ is a multiple of 4?

Comment: Sorry, my bad ! Sure we need two elements,  one more thing, does it matter if i create separate constraints for arr.sum(), arr.size() and arr.or()  or keep them in one . Are all conditions in single constraint solved parallelly like all separate constraints ?? Also can i use this lrm  i found online for reference  https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece411/fa2018/mp/SystemVerilog_3.1a.pdf

Comment: All constraints must be satisfied (evaluate to _true_). The use of separate constraint blocks helps you control them with `constraint_mode()` or override them when extending classes. But either way would not matter in this example. You should be using the free [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). The one you are referencing is nearly 20 years old.